# Picard groups and fundamental groups of subvarieties of projective space with small codimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Let $X$ be a subvariety of $\mathbb P_k^r$ of dimension $n$. If $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, then

(1). If $r \le 2n - 1$, then $X$ is simply connected ($X$ has trivial étale fundamental group).

(2). If $r \le 2n - 2$, then $\mathop{\mathrm{Pic}}(X) \cong \mathbb Z$.

If $k = \mathbb C$, then we can prove these statements using Barth's theorem, the general cases can be prove by reducing to $\mathbb C$. I wonder if there is an algebraic proof of the general case.

Comment: Have you looked at papers of Ogus?

Comment: (1) is proved in Fulton-Hansen, Ann. of Math. (2) 110 (1979), no. 1, 159-166. This is Corollary 2 on the first page.